# Identify values that are NOT contained in an existing range

Tags: sql

unable to find something that can solve this efficiently. Perhaps someone here has an idea? Everything I try is non-performant. I'm working with an input table(b) of 200M records and a dimension with 1M records.

I have 2 tables,

**Table A contains:**

TableA_Id(Int)

```
rangeValue_from (Int)
rangeValue_to (Int)
country (varchar)
```

-

-

**Table B contains**

TableB_ID(int)

```
value(Int)
```

So I need to join table A and table B together in such a way as to identify when the value from Table B is NOT within an existing range of Table A. ON b.Value BETWEEN a.rangeValue_from AND a.rangeValue_To

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: And you say the performance of `b LEFT JOIN a ON b.value BETWEEN a.x AND a.y WHERE a.id IS NULL` runs like a dog? Maybe list what you've tried that doesn't work so we don't suggest it again. Post the excursion plans of the failures so we can see why they were poor

Comment: Is the range inclusive or exclusive or a mix(what mix)?

Comment: What's the cardinality of each table?

Comment: What's the expected selectivity of the result? (what % of rows will be selected)

Comment: Hi Craig. This is most likely solvable (efficiently). What is the common/max range size?